# How to get all lines with matching texts in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a string here for practice.

```
$message = "Hurray! You've received a $100 Amazon Gift Card. Hope you enjoy this Amazon Gift Card! What's next? Apply the gift card to your Amazon account:=20 https://www.amazon.com/g/ Don't have an Amazon account? Sign up to redeem: www.amazon.com You can also redeem your gift card at checkout using this claim code: NE7N-TUD6NV-GUAB We hope to see you again soon, Amazon.com Once applied to your Amazon account, the entire amount will be added to you= r gift card balance. Your gift card balance can't be transferred to other a= ccounts, used to buy other gift cards, or, except as required by law, redee= med for cash. Your gift card balance will be applied automatically to eligible orders dur= ing the checkout process and when using 1-Click. If you don=E2=80=99t want = to use your gift card balance on your order, you can unselect it as a payme= nt method in checkout.=20 If you experience any issues using your gift card, you can reference your g= ift card by providing the following information to Customer Service: Order Number: 234343433433";
```

I want to get the claim code using preg_match but I fail. This is my code.

```
 if(preg_match_all("/claim code:.*\s/", $message, $array)){
           print_r($array);
       }
```

the output was this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => claim code: ) )
```

But i want it to show the claim code, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the pattern `(?<=\bclaim code: )\S+`:

```
$message = "Hurray! You've received a $100 Amazon Gift Card. Hope you enjoy this Amazon Gift Card! What's next? Apply the gift card to your Amazon account:=20 https://www.amazon.com/g/ Don't have an Amazon account? Sign up to redeem: www.amazon.com You can also redeem your gift card at checkout using this claim code: NE7N-TUD6NV-GUAB We hope to see you again soon, Amazon.com Once applied to your Amazon account, the entire amount will be added to you= r gift card balance. Your gift card balance can't be transferred to other a= ccounts, used to buy other gift cards, or, except as required by law, redee= med for cash. Your gift card balance will be applied automatically to eligible orders dur= ing the checkout process and when using 1-Click. If you don=E2=80=99t want = to use your gift card balance on your order, you can unselect it as a payme= nt method in checkout.=20 If you experience any issues using your gift card, you can reference your g= ift card by providing the following information to Customer Service: Order Number: 234343433433";
preg_match_all("/(?<=\bclaim code: )\S+/", $message, $matches);
print_r($matches[0][0]);
```

This prints:

```
NE7N-TUD6NV-GUAB
```

The main problem with your current approach is the regex pattern itself.  `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters, you should be using `\S*` instead as I have used above.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that goal using **positive lookbehind**. I would suggest to use `preg_match` unless you have more that one claim codes. Because `preg_match_all()` more memory consumer than `preg_match()`. For your solution, check out the following code:

```
$message = "Hurray! You've received a $100 Amazon Gift Card. Hope you enjoy this Amazon Gift Card! What's next? Apply the gift card to your Amazon account:=20 https://www.amazon.com/g/ Don't have an Amazon account? Sign up to redeem: www.amazon.com You can also redeem your gift card at checkout using this claim code: NE7N-TUD6NV-GUAB We hope to see you again soon, Amazon.com Once applied to your Amazon account, the entire amount will be added to you= r gift card balance. Your gift card balance can't be transferred to other a= ccounts, used to buy other gift cards, or, except as required by law, redee= med for cash. Your gift card balance will be applied automatically to eligible orders dur= ing the checkout process and when using 1-Click. If you don=E2=80=99t want = to use your gift card balance on your order, you can unselect it as a payme= nt method in checkout.=20 If you experience any issues using your gift card, you can reference your g= ift card by providing the following information to Customer Service: Order Number: 234343433433";

preg_match('/(?<=\bclaim\scode\b:\s)\S+/', $message, $matches);
echo $matches[0]; // NE7N-TUD6NV-GUAB
```

**Positive Lookbehind:**

> Ensures that the given pattern will match, ending at the current
>   position in the expression. The pattern must have a fixed width. Does
>   not consume any characters.

Syntax:

```
(?<=...)
```